# Where are EF Code-First Migrations Stored?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My situation is this - I just corrupted my SQL database. The only backup I have is from a number of migrations ago. Let's say I use the backup as my database now.

How do I apply the recent migrations. They have to be stored somewhere in the db...right?

I am not only asking for a fix, but interested in this theoretically - what exactly does `Get-Migrations` check? What is checked when I run `Update-Database`? I know a Migration file gets added to the project directory. But is it in the database somewhere too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations are code(with resources for model snaphot) which should be executed to change your db. There is a table in db which tracks last applied migration (MigrationHistory).

Comment: So, essentially, if I delete from that table, EF will think that those migrations have not been applied and will not return them in Get-Migrations, and will try to apply them on Update-Database?

Comment: Yep. But if you only delete rows from MigrationHistory, your model and db could become inconsistent and update-database could fail(because of repeating actions which were performed earlier).A correct way of removing your migrations is TargetMigration arg of update-database command with some previous migration as value.

Comment: I know the right way, but I often to have to pick up messed up databases / code from dear coworkers and fix it, so I would like to understand in detail.  Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Migrations are stored in the `__MigrationHistory` table of the database.

The `Model` column cintains a `GZip-compressed XML string` of you model.

You can see the following page for a nice write up
http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/03/inside_of_ef_migrations/